# Is it possible to complete Moonlit Grotto without using the teleporter in the midboss room?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-ages

I have played Oracle of Ages several times, and each time this has bothered me.

In all of the dungeons in Oracle of Seasons, and I believe all of them in Oracle of Ages with the exception of Moonlit Grotto, I was able to finish the dungeon without using the red teleporter that appears in the midboss room after beating the midboss.  However, it seemed to be necessary in order to complete Moonlit Grotto.  Is possible to complete this dungeon without teleporting to the midboss room to the entrance of the dungeon?

The problem I run into is that I need to get to the room east of the bumper on the second floor, as pictured here (star indicates where I want to go):

[image]

To do so, I need the bumper to be pointing clockwise when I reach the midboss room.  However, going to the midboss room from the west, the bumper sends me counterclockwise, so I can't get to the room with the boss key without using the teleporter to get to the room with the midboss and going south.

Is possible to complete this dungeon without teleporting to the midboss room to the entrance of the dungeon?

Comment: What makes you think you would need it? Just don't use it.  You should always be able to reach any location in a dungeon without having to use a teleporter... those are only there for your convenience.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to beat the dungeon without making use of the mini-boss teleport. It's actually faster to not make use of the teleport. The way you're supposed to get around it is to just take the same route you would use to get to the boss room, and then push the block directly across from the room. This will take you back to the mini-boss room, and allow you to get to the blocker from the North with the arrows taking you to the east.

The route to get you through is:

- Start in the mini-boss room
- Walk south to the bumper, which will move to the left and take you to the room west of the bumper room.
- Enter the room to the North, and continue proceeding North until you hit the room with the boss door (you'll need to make use of your seed shooter along the way)
- Push the block directly across from the boss room door, and go through the new opening. Proceed down the southern path on this side of the room.
- Proceed to the the East, which will return you to the mini-boss room. Once here simply proceed South to the bumper room again and it will take you to the Eastern room.

I've edited a [map of the dungeon from Neoseeker](http://www.neoseeker.com/resourcelink.html?rlid=102114) showing you the route. I had to switch to a white zig-zaggy line part-way through in order to differentiate the from the initial path you take upon leaving the mini-boss room.

[image]